# OpenGL Background color fader

Tags: c, opengl

How would I implement a routine using C with OpenGL to make the background color transition nicely from one color to another and then back again, repeatedly? All the colors I have in my palette are of 3 digit precision. From 0.000 to 1.000. It gets complex to have the color components  arrive at the second color in uniform timing, let alone adjusting the transition speed. Which I'm fine with keeping at 0.001 for now.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  The animation/timing, or the color mixing?

Comment: @genpfault the timing definitely. Just the basic algorithm of it. I'm gonna keep workin at it though. It's really mostly a failure of logic. I thought maybe someone would be bored enough to write it, then I could understand it and learn or at least implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question on genpfault's answer :

`glm::mix` (as well as GLSL's one) basically just does [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). In code that could mean something like

```
struct Color
{
    float r, g, b;
};

Color lerp(Color a, Color b, float t)
{
    Color c;
    c.r = (1-t)*a.r + t*b.r;
    c.g = (1-t)*a.g + t*b.g;
    c.b = (1-t)*a.b + t*b.b;

    return c;
}
```

Now, a common function to use to get back some back and forth effect is the [cosine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine).

The cosine gives you a value between -1 and 1, so you might want to scale it between 0 and 1. This can be done using

```
float t = cos(x) * 0.5 + 0.5; // *0.5 gets to [-0.5, 0.5], +0.5 gets to [0,1]
```

And you use this `t` to compute your color. The `x` can be the current time multiplied by some value that helps you control the speed of the interpolation.

EDIT:
Using gpenfault's code as a starting point, you can do this kind of stuff (if it poses any problem I remove it) :

```
// g++ main.cpp -lglut -lGL
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

int dstTime = 0; // milliseconds

struct Color
{
    float r, g, b;
};

Color makeColor(float r, float g, float b)
{
    Color c = { r, g, b };
    return c;
};

Color lerp(Color a, Color b, float t)
{
    Color c;
    c.r = (1-t)*a.r + t*b.r;
    c.g = (1-t)*a.g + t*b.g;
    c.b = (1-t)*a.b + t*b.b;

    return c;
}

void display()
{
    const int curTime = glutGet( GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME );

    // figure out how far along duration we are, between 0.0 and 1.0
    const float t = std::cos(float(curTime) * 0.001) * 0.5 + 0.5;

    // interpolate between two colors
    Color curColor = lerp(makeColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), makeColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), t);

    glClearColor( curColor.r, curColor.g, curColor.b, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 400,400 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I'm getting a compile error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'Color'  Color():Color(0,0,0) ..........I'm not too familiar with c or c++ (or structs), but is this c++ only? I'm using C. Is it easily adaptable?

Comment: Should be better like this

Comment: I had to add the strict keyword in front of a bunch of stuff and fix one typo but it's working beautifully with different colors too. Tyvm, you're amazing. Now to try and actually integrate into understanding...sigh...

Comment: Glad to help. If that answers your question please mark answer as accept to help others find answers easier !

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab the current time & calculate a time X milliseconds into the future
2. Each frame see how close you are to the future time (somewhere between 0% and 100% there)
3. Use the percentage value to interpolate between two colors
4. If the per-frame current time exceeds the destination time, reset the animation endpoints & set a new future time.

All together:

```
// g++ main.cpp -lglut -lGL
#include <GL/glut.h>

// http://glm.g-truc.net/
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int dstTime = 0; // milliseconds
glm::vec3 begColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glm::vec3 endColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

void display()
{
    const int duration = 3000; // milliseconds 
    const int curTime = glutGet( GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME );

    if( curTime > dstTime )
    {
        // reset animation parameters
        dstTime = curTime + duration;

        // swap colors
        const glm::vec3 tmpColor = begColor;
        begColor = endColor;
        endColor = tmpColor;
    }

    // figure out how far along duration we are, between 0.0 and 1.0
    const float u = ( curTime + duration - dstTime ) / (float)duration;

    // interpolate between two colors
    const glm::vec3 curColor = glm::mix( begColor, endColor, u );

    glClearColor( curColor.r, curColor.g, curColor.b, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 400,400 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry for the C++, [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) makes the color interpolation code very succinct.

Comment: I can't quite figure out how to implement the color mixing with the u variable without glm, and with colors besides black and white. Also the cycle repeats but I'd rather it go back and forth. But thanks for the post I still got some ideas from it.

Comment: Also I'd rather not use a timer to accomplish it. Just cause it seems unnecessary.

Comment: The problem with not using a timer (e.g using a global counter you increment instead) is that the speed of the animation will be related to the refresh speed. The quicker you render and get a new frame the quicker the animation will be.